Conditionally changing the pixel values in an RGB image, then removing the channels
I just want to compare the pixel of the image, if this pixel is pink (R value = 0.502, G value = 0.0, B value = 0.502) then change it to the color black, else change it to the color white. After this I want to remove the channels, to just have a (512,512,) shape tensor.
This getitem is inside my dataset class.
Code:
def __getitem__(self, index):
    img = Image.open(self.images[index]).convert("RGB") # this is one image
    mask = Image.open(self.masks[index]).convert("RGB") # this is the corresponding mask
    mask = self.transform_tensor(mask) # tensor is (3,512,512) shape
    mask = torch.where((mask[0, :, :] == 0.502) & (mask[1, :, :] == 0.0) & (mask[2, :, :] == 0.502), torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]), torch.tensor([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])) # error
    mask = self.transform_to_image(mask)
    mask.show()
    return self.transform_image(img), self.transform_mask(mask)

I get
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (512) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 1

Error: Unexpected type(s): (bool, Tensor, Tensor)


potentially more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79201018/changing-color-of-pixels-and-then-removing-the-channels

Rather than changing pixels and then removing channels, it seems like you really just need the boolean array of 'matches pink pixels', i.e.
arr = np.all(img == [0.502, 0, 0.502], axis=-1)

You may be able to use this as-is, but if you need pixel values multiply it by 1 or 255.

The easiest way should be minus the tensor with the vector, then take the absolute error w.r.t the corresponding channel, then do a thresholding. It can be implemented using just a single line of code:
mask = torch.rand(3,512,512)
color = torch.tensor([0.502,0,0.502]).view(-1,1,1)

mask = (mask - color).abs().sum(dim=0).gt(1e-7).float() # shape[512,512]

mask.shape # torch.Size([512, 512])

The above function can be transformed into (mask == color).all(dim= 0).
